# QXmlStreamReader: can't follow the flow of readNextStartElement()

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qxmlstreamreader

I have to implemenent a xml parser that constructs and places Qt objects in a widget in runtime. I wrote a parser based on [this](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/xml-streambookmarks.html). A module represents the `QWidget` that will hold the `QPushButton` and `QCheckBox` instances. `xml` is a `QXmlStreamReader`, just like the example from Qt reference.

So, here i try to parse through this very basic xml file:

```
<somexml version="1.0">
    <module>
        <button label="Send UART" define="BUTTON0" pos="30, 30" size="20, 10">
            <action cmd="sendCom" data="0xAA 0xBB 0xCC"/>
        </button>
        <checkbox label="Send UART" define="CHECKBOX0" pos="250, 30" size="20, 10">
            <action cmd="sendCom" data="test"/>
        </checkbox>
        <button label="Check BIT" define="BUTTON1" pos="140, 30" size="20, 10">
            <action cmd="setDef" data="BUTTON0=1"/>
        </button>   
    </module>
</somexml>
```

A module Element will create a widget to hold the checkboxes and pushbuttons within the tags. So here:

```
void XmlReader::readXml()
{
    while (xml.readNextStartElement())
    {
        if (xml.name() == "module")
        {
            readModule();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to read the module element and enter the scope of `readModule`, which it does. Inside of `readModule` i really have trouble following the flow of parsing.

Here is the implementation:

```
void XmlReader::readModule()
{
    Q_ASSERT(xml.isStartElement() && xml.name() == "module");


    while (xml.readNextStartElement())
    {
        if (xml.name() == "button")
        {
            readButton(widget);
        }
        else if (xml.name() == "checkbox")
        {
            readCheckBox(widget);
        }
        else
        {
            xml.skipCurrentElement();
        }
    }
}
```

It will only reach the first `button` element in the xml file and create one button. Send UART.

When i change the implementation of `readXml` to:

```
void XmlReader::readXml()
{
    while (xml.readNextStartElement())
    {
        if (xml.name() == "module")
        {
            readModule();
        }
        else if (xml.name() == "button")
        {
            readButton(widget);
        }
        else if (xml.name() == "checkbox")
        {
            readCheckBox(widget);
        }
        else
        { 
            xml.skipCurrentElement();
        }
    }
}
```

it will reach the first button and the first checkbox. What am i missing?

**EDIT: added implementation of readButton**

```
void XmlReader::readButton(Widget *widget)
{
    Q_ASSERT(xml.isStartElement() && xml.name() == "button");

    QString label = xml.attributes().value("label").toString();
    QString define = xml.attributes().value("define").toString();

    QString pos = xml.attributes().value("pos").toString();
    QStringList posList = pos.split(",");
    int posX = posList[0].toInt();
    int posY = posList[1].toInt();

    QString size = xml.attributes().value("size").toString();
    QStringList sizeList= size.split(",");
    int sizeX = sizeList[0].toInt();
    int sizeY = sizeList[1].toInt();

    QString cmd, data;

    while (xml.readNextStartElement())
    {
        if (xml.name() == "action") 
        {
            cmd = xml.attributes().value("cmd").toString();
            data = xml.attributes().value("data").toString();
        }
        else
        {
            xml.skipCurrentElement();
        }
    }

    if (cmd == "sendCom")
    {
        widget->createButton(label, define, posX, posY,
                SLOT(sendCom(QString)), data);
    }
    else if (cmd == "setDef")
    {
        widget->createButton(label, define, posX, posY,
                SLOT(setDef(QString)), data);
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you implemented `readButton(widget);`? Maybe after readButton `xml.readNextStartElement()` returns falls because it reads 'end element' (</button> for ex.) and the loop breaks.

Comment: added the implementation

Comment: Try to add `xml.readElementText();` after readButton and after readCheckBox. Or `xml.skipCurrentElement();` I Think that both will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `xml.skipCurrentElement();` after `readButton(widget);` and `readCheckBox(widget);`. Without that `xml.readNextStartElement()` reads end of element  and breaks the loop.

```
void XmlReader::readModule()
{
    Q_ASSERT(xml.isStartElement() && xml.name() == "module");

    while (xml.readNextStartElement())
    {
        if (xml.name() == "button")
        {
            readButton(widget);
            xml.skipCurrentElement();
        }
        else if (xml.name() == "checkbox")
        {
            readCheckBox(widget);
            xml.skipCurrentElement();
        }
        else
        {
            xml.skipCurrentElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but the term `skipCurrentElement` still sounds rather unintuitive to me.